# Event Webhook : GET parameters in URL

Tags: php, sendgrid, inbound

I have a Yii application without mod rewrite, the controller need to be set in URL : `?r=controller/action`
In the application : i want to create a system for [Event Wehook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/php-code-example#event-webhook)

I add this link https://example.com/?r=sendgrid/action to app.sendgrid.com/settings/parse : the action never happen : link never call (i just log it on a file for checking : direct call work like a charm).

I test on another way i create a checksendgrid.php file with

```php
    <?php
    $postedValues = $_POST;
    $gettedValues = $_GET;
    $values = [
        'post' => $postedValues,
        'get' => $gettedValues,
    ];
    $result = file_put_contents(
        '/var/log/test/sendgrid.log',
        json_encode($values),
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
    );
    file_put_contents(
        '/var/log/test/sendgrid.log',
        "\n",
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
    );
    $data = file_get_contents("php:/input");
    $events = json_decode($data, true);
    if(!empty($events)) {
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $result = file_put_contents(
                '/var/log/test/sendgrid.log',
                json_encode($event),
                FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
            );
            file_put_contents(
                '/var/log/test/sendgrid.log',
                "\n",
                FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
            );
        }
    }
    file_put_contents(
        '/var/log/test/sendgrid.log',
        "\n",
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
    );
```

Set this file on parse settings `example.org/checksendgrid?param=ok` and get only on log :

```
{"post":[],"get":[]}
{"bounce_classification":"Unclassified","category":["survey:441148"],"email":"invalid@mailinvalide-example.com","event":"bounce","ls-survey":"441148","ls-tid":"3","ls-token":"ezrzer","reason":"unable to get mx info: failed to get IPs from PTR record: lookup <nil>: unrecognized address","sg_event_id":"Ym91bmNlLTQtMzUyODUzODAtOFI1eTZKb3JSZjZTV01oaUI1Zlg1US0w","sg_message_id":"8R5y6JorRf6SWMhiB5fX5Q.filterdrecv-d7bbbc8bf-pldp9-1-64BA8FFE-40.0","smtp-id":"<kQboWY6eRJIzjnFpAw9q6xi1Ly4y2AwskpgEYQkK9Ek@oecd-dev.sondages.pro>","timestamp":1689948459,"tls":0,"type":"blocked"}
```

Is ther a way to have GET parameters in Inboud parse ?

Comment: Some providers only accept URLs without query strings for webhook URLs (some don't even like script file names in there, but want you to point them to a "directory" URL only.) If you can't get URL rewriting enabled for your system, maybe you can fake it by using your own little wrapper script - `/webhook.php`, and in there you set `$_GET['r'] = 'sendgrid/action';`, and then you just include your root level `index.php` after that.